# Predicting new subject observations in repeated measures data

Tags: mixed-model, glmm

### Dataset

Say I have a repeated measures dataset given as follows.

There are **10 subjects**, and each subject responded **100 times**.

```
    observ_idx    subj_idx    response
        1            1           20
        2            1           25
        3            1           14
        4            1           27
       ...          ...         ...
       101           2           65
       102           2           61
       103           2           68
       104           2           72
       ...          ...         ...
       ...          ...         ...
       901           10          32
       902           10          38
       903           10          37
       ...          ...         ...
      1000           10          29
```

---

### Problem

Say I would like to train from the above data, and wish to predict the responses of the new subject, **subject 11**.

There is no additional information for the subject 11(e.g. the 'mean' level of the subject 11). How should I proceed?

---

### Try

I think the generalized linear mixed model(**GLMM**) is the quite right decision, although I have not very often encountered the cases where GLMM is applied to this prediction problem.

As far as I know, we need to estimate the $\hat{\gamma}$ for each subject when we model GLMM, particularly [**mixed model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) as follows:

$$
y = X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon
$$

But after estimating the $\hat{\gamma}$ for the existing **10 subjects**, how should I predict 11th subject?

---

### Guess

Is it best to assume the **mean level** of **11th subject** is the mean of the whole existing data, when we have no additional info for her?

Any directions/help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no measurements for subject 11 available, you can base the predictions only on the estimated fixed-effects part $x_{11} \hat \beta$ of this subject, where $x_{11}$ denotes the covariates for this subject, i.e., you set the random effects $\gamma$ to zero.